# OpenVPN opens msn.com on Windows

Tags: windows, openvpn

I have asked my question on the OpenVPN forums, and I have not got a single response. So maybe I'll get some knowledge here.

I have my OpenVPN server on an RPi2 at home. I connect to it with the Android app and the Windows software.

But after updating (I had the 601 version, I got the 602 version because I had trouble with the TAP adapter. At the time I did not know that I had to install another separate TAP driver, which fixed the issue.) every time I connect to my VPN my browser (Chrome) opens the page msn.com.

This only happens on Windows, and I have tried rolling back to 601, but the issue persists.

I'm 99% sure that the issue is with OpenVPN, but I have been through all my configs and I can't find anything that relates to msn.com.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your network connection changes, Windows checks `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\EnableActiveProbing` value in the Registry and, if it is set to `1`, Windows (actually, Network Location Awareness service) tries querying the server specified by `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\ActiveWebProbeHost` value, which, by default, is set to `www.msftncsi.com`.

In case `ActiveWebProbeHost` (`www.msftncsi.com`) cannot be reached, it assumes you might need to authenticate to the network and it helpfully opens your IE homepage (http://www.msn.com) via the default browser (Chrome) for you. As your connection is actually working and you do not need any additional authentication, you end up with MSN page opened in Chrome.

In your case, I am pretty sure you can solve this by changing `EnableActiveProbing` value in the registry (under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet`) to `0`. Yet, I would consider this more as a workaround than the solution of the root problem.

If you are curious about the underlying problem, you might want to confirm that `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\ActiveWebProbeHost` is indeed set to `www.msftncsi.com` and not some other hostname and, if it really is, try pinging this hostname once the VPN connection is established, to make sure the host is really reachable through your OpenVPN tunnel. In case it is not, you can try setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\ActiveWebProbeHost` to a different hostname, which you are sure is reachable.